# is there any package for IP camera?

Tags: ros, camera-drivers, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

would anyone know a package able to connect to an IP camera and send its frames as sensor_msgs/Image?

Thanks

Raph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9911/is-there-any-package-for-ip-camera?/) by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1382 on 2011-05-06

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a gstreamer node gscam: http://www.ros.org/wiki/gscam

If you can figure out the gstreamer configureation to read from the camera's URI, it should work, though I have to say the gstreamer can be a bit difficult to configure at times. GSCAM_CONFIG would need to contain a gstreamer pipeline string that accessed the IP camera's URI. You'd need the correct gstreamer plugins, and you might find some info on how to configure , rtsp for example, here: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-rtspsrc.html

*(Edited to address comment)*

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-05-06**:
Thanks a lot. I will dig into that next week and if I manage it, post my gstreamer pipelinw.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-05-06**:
Yeah. Sorry, I should have been more specific, I'll edit the answer.

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-05-06**:
Sorry to ask, but what do you mean by the "gstreamer-foo" ? I only see gscam in the package. Do you mean I need to somehow work on the system variable GSCAM_CONFIG to get it to connect to my IP camera?

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-05-06**:
thanks, I'll look into that

**Comment by [Dipta](https://answers.ros.org/users/14186/dipta/) on 2014-04-01**:
Hello Raphael, is it working now? I also work on the same thing